# Auto-Py-To-Exe Warnings on pymssql

Tags: python-3.6, ubuntu-14.04, pymssql, auto-py-to-exe

I am currently working on Ubuntu 14.04. I am using PyMsSql in my program to connect with my database. I am using Anaconda3-4.3.1-Linux with Python3.6. Last time I tried to convert an executable file, it worked, but now after a month doing again it give doesn't run. I get this warning when I do Auto-Py-To-exe

95475 WARNING: Cannot find libk5crypto-b1f99d5c.so.3.1 (needed by /home/vboxuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymssql/../pymssql.libs/libkrb5-fcafa220.so.3.3)

95514 WARNING: Cannot find libcom_err-2abe824b.so.2.1 (needed by /home/vboxuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymssql/../pymssql.libs/libkrb5-fcafa220.so.3.3)

95601 WARNING: Cannot find libkrb5support-d0bcff84.so.0.1 (needed by /home/vboxuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymssql/../pymssql.libs/libkrb5-fcafa220.so.3.3)

95669 WARNING: Cannot find libkeyutils-dfe70bd6.so.1.5 (needed by /home/vboxuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymssql/../pymssql.libs/libkrb5-fcafa220.so.3.3)

95744 WARNING: Cannot find libkrb5support-d0bcff84.so.0.1 (needed by /home/vboxuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymssql/../pymssql.libs/libk5crypto-b1f99d5c.so.3.1)

95791 WARNING: Cannot find libkeyutils-dfe70bd6.so.1.5 (needed by /home/vboxuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymssql/../pymssql.libs/libk5crypto-b1f99d5c.so.3.1)

95932 WARNING: Cannot find libpcre-9513aab5.so.1.2.0 (needed by /home/vboxuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymssql/../pymssql.libs/libselinux-0922c95c.so.1)

96044 WARNING: Cannot find libkeyutils-dfe70bd6.so.1.5 (needed by /home/vboxuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymssql/../pymssql.libs/libkrb5support-d0bcff84.so.0.1)

96099 WARNING: Cannot find libselinux-0922c95c.so.1 (needed by /home/vboxuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymssql/../pymssql.libs/libkrb5support-d0bcff84.so.0.1)

96204 WARNING: Cannot find libkrb5-fcafa220.so.3.3 (needed by /home/vboxuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymssql/../pymssql.libs/libgssapi_krb5-497db0c6.so.2.2)

96235 WARNING: Cannot find libk5crypto-b1f99d5c.so.3.1 (needed by /home/vboxuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymssql/../pymssql.libs/libgssapi_krb5-497db0c6.so.2.2)

96300 WARNING: Cannot find libcom_err-2abe824b.so.2.1 (needed by /home/vboxuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymssql/../pymssql.libs/libgssapi_krb5-497db0c6.so.2.2)

96395 WARNING: Cannot find libkrb5support-d0bcff84.so.0.1 (needed by /home/vboxuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymssql/../pymssql.libs/libgssapi_krb5-497db0c6.so.2.2)

96448 WARNING: Cannot find libkeyutils-dfe70bd6.so.1.5 (needed by /home/vboxuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymssql/../pymssql.libs/libgssapi_krb5-497db0c6.so.2.2)

96562 WARNING: Cannot find libgssapi_krb5-497db0c6.so.2.2 (needed by /home/vboxuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymssql/../pymssql.libs/libssl-cd1d6220.so.1.0.2k)

96616 WARNING: Cannot find libkrb5-fcafa220.so.3.3 (needed by /home/vboxuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymssql/../pymssql.libs/libssl-cd1d6220.so.1.0.2k)

96691 WARNING: Cannot find libcom_err-2abe824b.so.2.1 (needed by /home/vboxuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymssql/../pymssql.libs/libssl-cd1d6220.so.1.0.2k)

96796 WARNING: Cannot find libk5crypto-b1f99d5c.so.3.1 (needed by /home/vboxuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymssql/../pymssql.libs/libssl-cd1d6220.so.1.0.2k)

96840 WARNING: Cannot find libcrypto-d3570994.so.1.0.2k (needed by /home/vboxuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymssql/../pymssql.libs/libssl-cd1d6220.so.1.0.2k)

I tried installing and uninstalling pymssql. conda install -c anaconda pymssql.